# Open another form in Qt android

Tags: android, c++, qt

How i can show another form using Qt android cross plat form application ?
I tried that by :

```
 dialog.exec();
```

or:

```
dialog.show();
```

but the result not as we expect it's partially shown on top of the previous form.

Comment: this is not an answer, but using c++ Ui in android i just wrong. use qml as ui and c++ for your core/engine.

Comment: yes i do this.Thank you.

Comment: Amr, If you still need that, try calling  hide() or even close() to the parent widget before showing the dialoge

Comment: I use Qt C++ UI on Android/iOS without any problems... But on new projects we are using QML.

Answer (score 1):

You can use showMaximized that will make your Dialog use all screen, or you can use setGeometry to put the widget where you want.

More info: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-33135

Answer (score 0):

if u want to open another form, just hide the old form and show the new form.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).